# Drizzle problem: how to connect to infura direct when user has Metamask, but isn't connected?

Tags: truffle, infura, drizzle

I understand how to connect direct to infura if the user has no wallet at all (for displaying blockchain data when users don't have a wallet) the problem is that I don’t know how to connect to infura when users have Metamask installed, but not logged in or connected.

Drizzle is default to MM (if installed) and requires them to connect.

I want to use infura as default for everyone, UNLESS they press the connect button -> then I want to switch to MM.

I’ve tried to change the web3 provider on the fly in window.web3 - didn’t work

I’ve tried to put infura in drizzleOptions as a custom provider - didn’t work

I’ve tried to use different drizzleOptions files for each case - didn’t work

What am I missing?